# Can I use Joomla's community builder as a form component?

Tags: php, component

I was developing a website that allows people to enter records. At the time, Community Builder was the best component for the job. The client was not clear if the records were a one-time thing or not, so I opted for Community Builder.

The problem is now the client wants the system to be able to allow a user to enter multiple records without overwriting the previous record, of which Community Builder does not allow as it is more of a profile component and restarting the whole system would be a lot of work and might take about two weeks as I have about ten different forms with multiple fields. Is there a plugin or any other way that I can allow a user to have multiple records or registrations using the same credentials in Community Builder?

Comment: Depending on what the form's purpose is, it sounds to me like you need a table that just keeps a record of the date created, modified and user id associated to the data.
That is not a huge task. You could use F0F which makes it fairly quick and simple and (deprecated) FOF is baked into the cms or check out component creator. With a little more detail in the question you might get a more straight forward answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to second @MOLEDesign and say that using Community Builder for this purpose is going to cause you more headaches in the long run than it will solve problems in the short term.

It's worth your time (and a small fee) to get a proper forms component and learn how to use it. It's knowledge you can use here and on every other project you work on in the future.

I'll throw in my suggestion for [RSForm Pro](http://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/joomla-form.html). It has handled everything I've ever needed in a form component, and it's not difficult for clients to get useful data and reports out of after I've handed the project off.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch... thats a bit of a pickle.

As you seem to have embedded the forms as part of the profile in your current system, I cant see how you can use multiple submissions against one profile without a hack.

There MAY be a CB plugin you can use but having spent 5 mins looking, I cant see any that will be fit for purpose

Honestly, save yourself some time now and go for a proper form component called Breezing forms (free trial available) which is so simple to create new forms its obscene! It also keeps proper, exportable records in the backend, allows scripting, paging, custom reports and emails.

Yeah, it may mean some leg work now, but once you get your head around breezing forms drag and drop functionality, you will be creating multi-paged forms in no time at all with full verification and responsive layouts (its bases itself on bootstrap).

www.crosstec.de for the component.

Sorry for the not so good news in this answer, but you wont be the first person I have seen use Community Builder for a non standard function and suffer for it a year or so later